# Displaying a large image next to 3 smaller images

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm setting up a layout in PyQT5, and I want one large image on the left side to be displayed next to 3 images that are 1/3 the height of the big image (so that the combined heights of the smaller images adds up to the height of the large image)

Here's the code in the class Layout, which starts and displays the gui. All images are loaded in the createGridLayout method:

```py
class Layout(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Imaging'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 500
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.createGridLayout()

        windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        windowLayout.setSpacing(0)
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(windowLayout)

        self.show()

    def createGridLayout(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox()
        layout = QGridLayout()

        # label is the large image in the grid
        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('snap_1,1.tif') # USE RELATIVE PATH TO IMAGE!
        pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(450)
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)

        # simplified version of the above for small images
        label1 = QLabel(self)
        label1.setPixmap(QPixmap('snap_1,1.tif').scaledToHeight(150))

        label2 = QLabel(self)
        label2.setPixmap(QPixmap('snap_1,2.tif').scaledToHeight(150))

        label3 = QLabel(self)
        label3.setPixmap(QPixmap('snap_1,3.tif').scaledToHeight(150))

        # adding images to grid
        layout.addWidget(label,1,0)
        layout.addWidget(label1,0,1)
        layout.addWidget(label2,1,1)
        layout.addWidget(label3,2,1)

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)
```

All the imaging stuff is hardcoded for testing, which is to be accounted to later, yet not part of this issue.

So what I want is something like in the following image (Black boxes representing an image):

[image: Wanted result]

But what I'm currently getting is something like this:

[image: Current result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to obtain the following structure:

```
┌---------┬---------┐
|         |         |
|         ├---------┤
|         |         |
|         ├---------┤
|         |         |
└---------┴---------┘
```

Then you must analyze the structure, the item on the left starts at (0, 0) and has 3 rows and 1 column so the addWidget() method must pass (0, 0, 3, 1)

```
# ...
# adding images to grid
layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0, 3, 1)
layout.addWidget(label1, 0, 1)
layout.addWidget(label2, 1, 1)
layout.addWidget(label3, 2, 1)
# ...
```